# PHP recursive function not returning anything to AJAX request

Tags: php

I'm rewording this question in hopes of it being a articulated a bit better. I am using AJAX to pass a string to this PHP script. The PHP script takes a string of words, breaks them into an array, and tries to analyze each word. The problem I'm having is that it is not responding to the AJAX request if there is a word it cannot analyze. I wanted it to return the word itself if a word cannot be broken down, but it seems to be skipping over this line.

I'm also not sure of how to make this script into something you could easily test on your own computers, given that it has so many moving parts. I've pulled out the relevant HTML, JS, and PHP code. Let me know if any more would be helpful, or if there is anyway I can clarify things.

I'm a Python programmer working with PHP for the first time, and I'm having a hard time debugging this.

```
<?php  

class MorphologyAnalyzer
{
    protected $affixes;
    public function customSort($a,$b){
        // sort compares based on string length
        if(mb_strlen($b, 'UTF-8') == mb_strlen($a, 'UTF-8')){
            return 0;
        }
        return (mb_strlen($a, 'UTF-8') < mb_strlen($b, 'UTF-8')) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->affixes = array();
        // draw affixes from the Phrasicon
        $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmlDoc->load("../../morphemes/morphemes.xml");
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

        $result = $xpath->query("//source");

        foreach($result as $entry) {
            // building the list $affixes. Basically, take all possible affixes and exclude duplicates
            $m = $entry->nodeValue;
            if (!in_array($m, $this->affixes)) {
                array_push($this->affixes, $m);
            }
        }

        // sort affixes by length? why the calls to both sort and usort?
        sort($this->affixes);
        usort($this->affixes, array($this, 'customSort'));
    }



    public function beginsWith($haystack, $needle) {
        if(strlen($haystack) <= strlen($needle)){
            return FALSE;
        } else{
            return $needle === "" || strpos($haystack, $needle) !== FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
        if(strlen($haystack) <= strlen($needle)){
            return FALSE;
        } else{
            return $needle === "" || strpos($haystack, $needle, strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) !== FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function analyze($word){   // to analyze each word: recursion! Yay!
        if($word == ""){
            return "";
        } else{
            for($a=0; $a<count($this->affixes); $a++) {
                $affix = $this->affixes[$a];
                // cut off the initial hyphen that is on the affixes
                if(substr($affix, 0, 1) == "-"){
                    $affix = substr($affix, 1);
                } elseif(substr($affix, -1, 1) == "-"){
                    $affix = substr($affix, 0, -1);
                };

                // if the whole word matches a given morpheme, just return it.
                if($word == $affix){
                    return $word;
                } elseif ($this->endsWith($word,$affix) !== FALSE) {
                    // we need to add a call here that recursively calls analyze on smaller and smaller strings
                    // transform the word from hayunam to hayu-nam, I think
                    return $this->analyze(preg_replace('/'.$affix.'$/', '', $word)) . " -" . $affix;      
                }
            }
            // return the word if no match was found
            return $word;
        }
    }
}

?>

<?php

$txt = $_GET['text'];

// split input text into a list of words. 
$words = explode(' ', $txt);

// this is the text that will be returned ultimately -- it will be a list of morphemes
$morphemes = "";

// create an analyzer
$analyzer = new MorphologyAnalyzer();

// go through the list of words...
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($words); $i++){
    // the current word
    $word = $words[$i]; 
    $morphemes = $morphemes . $analyzer->analyze($word) . " "; 
}
// return the list of morphemes at the end.
echo rtrim($morphemes);


?>
```

Here is the relevant JS

```
function segment(line) {
            // this code segments the source text in the "create story" section
            var lineNumber = line.split("line")[1];
            var lineSource = document.getElementById((line + "_source")).value;
            var morphemes = document.getElementsByClassName((lineNumber + "morpheme"));
            var morphemeCounter = morphemes.length;
                    // if source is blank, fill in all the morphemes with blanks
            for (i = 1; i <= morphemeCounter; i++) {
                document.getElementById(line + "_m" + i).value = "";
                document.getElementById(line + "_g" + i).value = "";
            }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        response = xmlhttp.responseText.trim().split(" ");
                        console.log("response" + response)
                        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                            // if there aren't any remaining morpheme spaces to segment the text...
                            if(document.getElementById(line + '_m' + (i + 1))==null){
                                // ... add one.
                                addMorpheme((line + "_m" + (i+1)));
                            }
                            document.getElementById(line + '_m' + (i + 1)).value = response[i];
                       }
                       suggest(response[i], ((line + '_g') + (i)));
                    }
                }
                console.log(lineSource)
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "segmentation.php?text="+lineSource, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

Here is the HTML

```
    <h3 class="text-center">Story Text</h3>
    <div class="container-fluid bodyContainer" id="lineContainer">
        <fieldset id="line1">
            <h4>Line 1</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    Source<br/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="line1_source" name="line[0][source]">
                    <a id="line1_segmentation" class="btn btn-success" onclick="segment('line1')">Segment&nbsp; <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    Translation<br/>
                    <input class="form-control" id="line1_translation" type="text" name="line[0][translation]">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    Hints/Notes (for comparing multiple versions of a story)<br/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="line[0][note]">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    Audio Filename<br/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="line[0][lineaudio]">
                </div>
            </div>

            <h5>Morphemes</h5>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input id="line1_m1" class="1morpheme" type="text" name="line[0][morpheme][0][m]" onkeyup="suggest(this.value, 'line1_g1')">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input id="line1_g1" type="text" name="line[0][morpheme][0][g]" list="list_line1_g1" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_line1_m1" onclick="deleteMorpheme('line1_m1')"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Morpheme 1</a>
                    &nbsp;
                    <a class="btn btn-info" id="addMorpheme_line1_m1" onclick="addMorpheme('line1_m2')"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <a class="btn btn-info" onclick="addLine()">+ Add Line</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Create">Create&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-rocket"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="datalistContainer">
    <datalist id="list_line1_g1">
        <option value=" "></option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

The XML file morphemes.xml contains entries like the following:

```
<morpheme>
    <source>hayu</source>
    <gloss>dog</gloss>
</morpheme>
```

For a string like hayunam xyz (where the first word can be broken down, and the second one cannot), I expect it to return hayu -nam xyz

Comment: What do you have in the .xml file, what is the test data that you run and finally what is the result you expect and the result you have?

Comment: I probably would have used Regex for the end matches, `/(affix1|affix2|affix3)$/` instead of the loop, but what do I know.  And trim instead of this `substr($affix, 0, 1) == "-"`  such as `trim($affix,'-')`  Because then you don't even need the if condition there.

Comment: @ThanasisPap I edited the answer to include that information. Right now, if it comes across a word it cannot break down, it will not return anything to the AJAX request

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I need recursion and the loop because there are thousands of possible affixes, the list grows daily, and a word may have multiple affixes attached.

Comment: `I wanted it to return the word itself if a word cannot be broken down, but it seems to be skipping over this line`  It can's skip over a line, what does it return instead, I take it it's `analyze` your talking about?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the AJAX request is getting a response of an empty string from the PHP script. If it can parse everything, it works as intended. If it finds a single word it does not recognize, it is returning an empty string.

Comment: Check your server error log to see if there's a PHP error being thrown resulting in your script not generating a response.  Alternatively: Write a PHP script that can be executed from the CLI that exercises your PHP code and asserts that given a set of inputs, you get the expected outputs.

Comment: Thanks @dossy. I might have to do that, because the server error log is empty at the moment.

Comment: @dossy is right; you need to check CLI response. A good way to do this is with Curl. You could also add some debugging output into your php temporarily then.